# Flink error when instantiating Jackson Object Mapper

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am new to Flink and have encountered a weird behavior that I do not understand.

Here is a basic example of my code :

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);

env.addSource(MY_KAFKA_SOURCE)
   .map(m -> {
       String myStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
       return myStr.getBytes();
   })
   .addSink(MY_ELASTICSEARCH_SINK);

try {
    env.execute();
}catch (Exception e){
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

When I do so, my code work as expected in local. But when I try to run it on a Flink cluster (through the Flink Web Dashboard), I get the following error (and nothing more) :

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program caused an error:
```

After some tests, I found out two things that I don't know how to interpret :

- I always have this error when I initialize a `new ObjectMapper();`, even if it is not used anywere. (If I remove the ObjectMapper, the code run without error, but I need it :) )
- When I declare my ObjectMapper inside the map function, the code works well.

In my code I also have a custom Map function declared in another class and used as follow :

```
public class MyCustomFunction implements MapFunction<Row, Map<String, Object>> {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CustomRowToMapFunction() {
        // Do something
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Map<String, Object> map(Row elt) throws Exception {
        // Do something
    }
}

env.addSource(MY_KAFKA_SOURCE)
   .map(new MyCustomFunction())
   .map(m -> {
       String myStr = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(m);
       return myStr.getBytes();
   })
   .addSink(MY_ELASTICSEARCH_SINK);
```

In the same way as previously, if I initialize a `new ObjectMapper();` in the constructor, and even if it is not used anywere or only in the constructor, I get my Flink error. If I initialize the ObjectMapper in the map() function I get no error.

As you can understand, I am a bit lost in this. If anyone have idea or explanation of what is happening here ?

Notes :

- I am using Flink 1.7.2 (Tried with Flink 1.8.0)
- ObjectMapper is from FasterXML Jackson Core 2.9.9

Comment: Non-serializable objects should be initialized in the `open`-Method of any `Rich***`-Function. Implement the `RichMapFunction` and override the `open` method to initialize the ObjectMapper

Comment: It looks like it's what I am looking for ! But I don't understand where the `Configuration` object in the open function come from.

Comment: the methods is called by flink and the `Configuration` object is created by flink. You don't have to call the method yourself. I'm not sure what the `Configuration` object contains ATM but I've never bothered about it and just ignored it.
Just another note: all fields you initialize inside the `open`-Method should be marked as `transient`.

EDIT: I don't have the time for an full answer right now, that's why I'm only commenting. If I find the time for an full answer I'll do.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to make it work (the Configuration object look like historical code here to keep compliance with old flink). To pass parameters to the function, I needed  to pass parameters through the constructor and then use them in the class.